.NET MAUI: The light and dark modes are not properly updating on the iOS platform
When I switch the mode from light to dark or dark to light on the Home page, the mode does not properly change on the iOS platform but works fine on the Android platform. That means on the home page, the outer frame is updating based on the mode, but the inner frame is not updating based on the mode. But when I close the app and again open the app, the home page is properly updated based on the mode. Below, I am adding a screenshot of the issues in both modes.
Screenshots:
Light Mode:

Dark Mode:

I am using the below code changing the mode.
public async void ChangetoLight(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new ModeChangeMessage("modechanged"));
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + exc);
    }
}

public async void ChangetoDark(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new ModeChangeMessage("modechanged"));
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + exc);
    }
}

The above WeakReferenceMessenger is subscribed on the Home page:
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ModeChangeMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    if (m.Value == "modechanged")
    {
        SetMode();
    }
});

private void SetMode()
{
    try
    {
        mode = Preferences.Default.Get("mode", "light");
        if (mode == "light")
        {
            LightMode();
        }
        else if (mode == "dark")
        {
            DarkMode();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + e);
        Preferences.Default.Set("mode", "light");
        mode = "light";
        LightMode();
    }
}

private void LightMode()
{
    home_layout.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
    homelistview.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
}

private void DarkMode()
{
    home_layout.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#434343");
    homelistview.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#434343");
}

After mode change we are updating the color of homelistview and home_layout. But as per the above screenshot the color is not updating.
ListView XAML:
<Frame
    Grid.Row="0"
    Style="{StaticResource InnerFrameStyle}"
    x:Name="home_layout">

    <ListView   
        x:Name="homelistview"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        SelectionMode="None"
        Margin="10"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        ItemTapped="HomeOptionsTapped"
        SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Frame
                            HasShadow="False"
                            Padding="8"
                            CornerRadius="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=30}"
                            BorderColor="#bdbdbd"
                            Margin="5"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}">

                                <StackLayout 
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    TextColor="{Binding TextColor}">
                                    </Label>

                                    <Image 
                                    Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                    </Image>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.Footer>
            <Label/>
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
</Frame>

Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue? This issue is only on iOS platform.
Update
I have created a sample project and uploaded it here. Click on any option and change the mode. The UI is not updating LIVE, but updating when reopens the app.
We tried setting the Backgroundcolor as per your suggestion, but no luck. Please check the below screenshot.
Expected UI:

Current UI:


This issue is related with https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16531.  Consider wrapping the ListView with a Grid or Border instead of Frame and then setting the Backgroundcolor for the former ones.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT We tried this solution, but it is not working

@AlexandarMay-MSFT We have added a sample project on the question, could you please check that?

What .NET version you are using? Consider using .NET 8 to see if it works!

@AlexandarMay-MSFT we are using .NET 7.0 and the problem occurs in iOS simulator. macOS version 14.4.1

Thanks for your response. Please use .NET 8 to see if it works.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT We tried with .NET 8, but it is not working.

Please try set different BGColor in Light Mode and Dark Mode, if that still doesn't work, please follow the issue:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16531 on Github.

This issue is fixed and fixed with the below link
